# Mysql Drop Table as PreparedStatement not working for me

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

This prepared statement seems like valid SQL to me.

```
PreparedStatement dropTable = cnx.prepareStatement(
    "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ?");
dropTable.setString(1, "features");
dropTable.execute();
```

But when I run this, I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''features'' at
>   line 1    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
>     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1031)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2648)   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2077)
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1356)
>     at doriangray.db.TestSetup.main(TestSetup.java:62)

Does anyone see the problem here? I'm stumped.

Comment: I'm not into Java, but all prepared statements libraries I know don't support dynamic table names.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MySQL doesn't support prepared statements with variable table names, so you have to do this the old fashioned way, by generating SQL:

```
PreparedStatement dropTable = cnx.prepareStatement(
String.format("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s", "features"));
dropTable.execute();
```

In this case you might as well use regular statements since you don't gain anything by using prepared statements.

Answer (score 3):

I think your code prepares this statement:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'features'
```

while you want:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS features
```

Answer (score 1):

PreparedStatements are used for making database compile the query (make the execution plan) once, so  executing the same query with different parameters happens faster.

In short in a PreparedStatement you can not have a wildcard for database objects. Including table name, column name, different where clauses and ....

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a prepared statement to drop tables with a dynamic table names. However, if you don't know the table names until run-time, and they could have spaces in them, then you'll need to enclose them in back-ticks:

```
for (String tableName : tableNames) {
    statement.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `" + tableName + "`");
}
```